# Wrong vertical spacing in twocolumn mode

Tags: two-column, double-sided

I want a consistent spacing between the top of the page and the table-of-content-title/ chapter-titles throughout my document. However, in two-column mode, it appears that the space between the top of the page and chapter-title is a little bit smaller than the space between the top of the page and the table-of-content-title:

[image]

In one-column mode, the spacing is always the same. How can I keep the spacing equal in two-column mode?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\twocolumn % Comment this out and the spaces become right again

\chapter{Test Chapter}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a vertical space missing before the chapter-titles. But there is the same problem with the standard classes, see this [entry in the LaTeX bugs database](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3126&category=LaTeX&responsible=anyone&state=open&keyword=&search=).

As a workaround with KOMA-Script versions 3.16 or newer (3.17a is the current version on CTAN) you could use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\topskip}\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
\BeforeTOCHead{\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\@tempskipa}}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code (without the grid):

```
\documentclass[open=any,
  twocolumn
]{scrbook}[2015/02/07]
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\topskip}\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
\BeforeTOCHead{\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\@tempskipa}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

---

And as reference: The same code without twocolumn and without the workaround

```
\documentclass[open=any,
  %twocolumn
]{scrbook}[2015/02/07]
\usepackage{showframe}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\topskip}\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
%\BeforeTOCHead{\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\@tempskipa}}}
%\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

---

**Update**

If you want to switch between `twocolumn` and `onecolumn` inside the document you could use something like

```
\documentclass[open=any,
  twocolumn
]{scrbook}[2015/02/07]
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tcchapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{\topskip}\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
\newcommand*\occhapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\tcchapterheadstartvskip}
\BeforeTOCHead{\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\occhapterheadstartvskip}}

\newcommand\mytwocolumn{%
  \KOMAoptions{twocolumn=true}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\tcchapterheadstartvskip}%
}
\newcommand\myonecolumn{%
  \KOMAoptions{twocolumn=false}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\occhapterheadstartvskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\KOMAScriptVersion

\clearpage
\myonecolumn
\chapter{Test Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

\clearpage
\mytwocolumn
\chapter{Test Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, the definiton of `\tcchapterheadstartvskip` have to be changed if the `parskip` Option is used.

With `parskip` or `parskip=full`:

```
\newcommand*\tcchapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{\topskip}\vspace{\baselineskip}\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
```

And with `parskip=half`:

```
\newcommand*\tcchapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{\topskip}\vspace{.5\baselineskip}\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I have noticed that the same wrong spacing appears also for the bibliography.

Comment: @klopps There is no bibliography in your MWE. Nevertheless maybe my updated answer will help.